# Displaying a suit symbol in terminal from Java

Tags: java, ascii

I have a question regarding displaying a suit symbol (ASCII) (heart, diamond, spade, and club) to the terminal window when running a Java program. I currently use JCreator V3 LE. The JDK I use is 1.8.0_172.

In the past, I used the syntax:

```
Character.toString((char) 3)
Character.toString((char) 4)
Character.toString((char) 5)
Character.toString((char) 6)
```

Now, it displays a box with a ? in it, as if the character cannot be found. Is there another way to do this, or has this character been eliminated from the window?

Thanks.

Comment: What OS is this? Does the terminal support unicode?

Comment: How your terminal displays non-printable characters is dependent on terminal settings. Note that the suit symbols are not those: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode#Card_suits. You're better off using actual characters instead of relying on chance.

Comment: The ASCII values 0-31 are non-printable characters or whitespace. U+0003 is "end of text" for example. ASCII doesn't have card suits in.

Comment: I've tried using unicode: '\u2660', '\u2665', '\u2663', and '\u2666', but it also does not work and displays a "?" when I use it.

Comment: Then fix your terminal to display the characters you want to be able to use in it. Non-printable chars are just that; non-printable: it will not work reliably. Of course, if you're running in a terminal that doesn't support Unicode, that won't work either, but at least Unicode is an actual thing.

Comment: How do I fix my terminal, so that it could display these characters? It has worked for years when I did this.

Comment: No clue, because I have no clue what terminal you're using. Most support unicode now.

Comment: Mine displays a "?" whenever I use '\u2660' or something of the sort. The terminal I believe is built into JCreator.

Comment: Then you'd need to either change the font to one that supports more Unicode, or [something else, no clue].

Comment: The `?` leads me to suspect you’re running in Windows.  There is no good way to make a command window display Unicode.  Some workarounds exist, but last I heard, they were not reliable.  Consider using a user interface library like JavaFX or Swing instead.

Answer (score 2):

As with all text transfers, your Java program (writer) and terminal (reader) need to be on the same page—"code page" (character encoding), that is. You said ASCII but ASCII doesn't support the characters you want to use. You are probably thinking of CP437 from MS-DOS and Windows. (MS-DOS didn't have an ASCII code page; Windows got one late in life, for the sake of completeness. ASCII is only used is very specialized contexts.)

If you want to take Java's character transcoding out of the equation, you can write bytes to the output stream. Then whatever they mean to the terminal, it will decode them to characters.

```
// for illustration purposes only; I would not invest in code like this.
System.out.flush();
System.out.write(0x03);
System.out.flush();
```

To actually see them, the terminal has to have a font that includes the decoded character. A white box or box with question mark indicate that the font doesn't. A question mark or question mark in a black diamond indicate that the bytes don't mean anything in the terminal's character encoding.

To check your terminal's character encoding, go `chcp` (Windows) or `locale` (most other OSes).

As @VGR stated in the comments, GUIs are simpler. This is because they avoid the concept of creating a byte stream of text in a particular character encoding and just use the windowing system's facility for drawing text. (This comes at the cost of not being able to pipe the output to another program or redirect it to a file, which is a key feature of CUI programs.)